# Complex filtering SQL Server query with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a SQL Server query in which I am joining several tables together and we are using SQL Server 2012. I have a customer number, customer name, item type, a field for document number (which can be one document number in either of the two tables I will mention; even though there are two fields mentioned later, I do want to combine this into one field using a CASE statement), a document amount, document date, due date, amount remaining to be paid, and a description.

The problem is that for my item type, one table (`RM20101`), doesn't recognize an item type associated with it because no item types are in that table. The other table (`Custom_RecData`), recognizes the correct item type for all pertinent document numbers but that tables only has a record of document numbers associated with items--which not all document numbers in the system have.

So here's an example of the trimmed down version:

```
CUSTNMBR    |  ItemType    |   DocumentNumberRM |  DocNumCUSTOM | DocAmount
------------+--------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   PYMNT01234567    |  NULL         |  - 28.50
12345ABC    |  TOYS        |   9010456778       |  9010456778   |   300.00
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   9010456778       |  NULL         |   300.00
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   9019888878       |  NULL         |    47.90
12345ABC    |  CRAFTS      |   9502345671       |  9502345671   |   145.25
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   9502345671       |  NULL         |   145.25
```

I named the columns in this example for document number as "RM" to come out of the `RM20101` table and "CUSTOM" to come out of the `Custom_RecDate` table.

So I've tried lots of ways, from CASE statements, to my WHERE clause, to a HAVING clause, to subqueries...  I can't figure it out.  Here's what I'd like to see:

```
CUSTNMBR    |  ItemType    |   DocumentNumberRM |  DocNumCUSTOM | DocAmount
------------+--------------+--------------------+---------------+-----------
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   PYMNT01234567    |  NULL         |  - 28.50
12345ABC    |  TOYS        |   9010456778       |  9010456778   |   300.00
12345ABC    |  NULL        |   9019888878       |  NULL         |    47.90
12345ABC    |  CRAFTS      |   9502345671       |  9502345671   |   145.25
```

So why did I call this multiple conditions?  Well, if you look at the table, I am cutting out items based on the following:

1. If both the `ItemType` And `DocNumCUSTOM` fields are NULL then show it.
2. If the `ItemType` IS NOT NULL and both document number fields are NOT NULL, then show it.
3. If the `ItemType` IS NULL and `DocNumCUSTOM` IS NULL, but we've already seen the document number in the `RM20101` `DocumentNumberRM` field (which I suspect would be in a HAVING clause for a COUNT or something), then don't show it a second time.

If I don't find a way to do step 3, I will get the duplicates as shown in my initial example.

**I basically do not want duplication.**  I want to show an item type whether it be NULL (non-existent for that document number in either table) or show it **only once** if existent in the `Custom_RecDate` table, which is the only table that has the item type information in it.

Does this make sense?  I know it sounds complicated as heck, but hopefully someone can make sense of it all.  :)

Thanks!

By the way, here's the important part (my query, albeit very trimmed down for the example):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    R1.CUSTNMBR,
    I.ITMCLSCD AS [ItemType],
    R1.DOCNUMBR AS [DocumentNumberRM],
    I.DOCNUMBR AS [DocNumCUSTOM],
    R1.ORTRXAMT AS [DocAmount]
FROM
    RM20101 R1
JOIN 
    RM40401 R2 ON R2.RMDTYPAL = R1.RMDTYPAL
JOIN 
    RM00401 R3 ON R3.DOCNUMBR = R1.DOCNUMBR
JOIN 
    RM00101 R4 ON R4.CUSTNMBR = R1.CUSTNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    SR_ITCMCD C ON C.CUSTNMBR = R1.CUSTNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    AR_Description D ON D.SOPNUM = R1.DOCNUMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Custom_RecData I ON I.ITEMNMBR = C.ITEMNMBR 
                     AND I.DOCNUMBR = R1.DOCNUMBR
```

Again, I've tried using `CASE` statements and putting various conditions in my `WHERE` clause, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s, for editing the question.  It looks nicer now with better formatting!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely based on the sample data, `MAX()` should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    R1.CUSTNMBR,
    MAX(I.ITMCLSCD) AS [ItemType],
    R1.DOCNUMBR AS [DocumentNumberRM],
    MAX(I.DOCNUMBR) AS [DocNumCUSTOM],
    R1.ORTRXAMT AS [DocAmount]
FROM RM20101 R1
JOIN RM40401 R2 ON R2.RMDTYPAL = R1.RMDTYPAL
JOIN RM00401 R3 ON R3.DOCNUMBR = R1.DOCNUMBR
JOIN RM00101 R4 ON R4.CUSTNMBR = R1.CUSTNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN SR_ITCMCD C ON C.CUSTNMBR = R1.CUSTNMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN AR_Description D ON D.SOPNUM = R1.DOCNUMBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN Custom_RecData I ON I.ITEMNMBR = C.ITEMNMBR 
                                AND I.DOCNUMBR = R1.DOCNUMBR
GROUP BY 
    R1.CUSTNMBR,
    R1.DOCNUMBR,
    R1.ORTRXAMT
```

Removed the `DISTINCT` since `GROUP BY` will accomplish the same and is needed for `MAX()`

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar.  Such a simple solution, I can't believe I didn't even think of that!  My query was a little more complex than the example one I gave you, but your solution was expanded to encompass the whole query I am working with.  Thank you!